# Why are my virtual consoles disabled?

Tags: lubuntu, virtual-console

I use Lubuntu 16.04. My `/etc/defaults/console-setup` says:

```
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
```

yet when I Ctrl+Alt+F1, or F2, or F3 etc. - I only see a black screen with the top line saying: "/dev/sda1: clean 123/456 files, 654/321 blocks" - no login prompt. I can switch back with Ctrl+Alt+F7, but, still - why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because your graphics driver is not working properly.  Pick another one from the drivers selection and see if it is fixed.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Would you mind linking to someplace explaining how I do that exactly? I mean, I'm able (with some pain) to edit `xorg.conf`'s, but I'm not sure which selection you're referring to.

Comment: dash, "additional drivers"

Comment: @Rinzwind: Sorry, I'm not following. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: about what? check to see if you can install another driver for your videocard. see the program " additional drivers" from my last comment.

Comment: There is no program named "additional drivers" that I know of... I tried looking for that with `apt-cache search` and with `locate` and came up with nothing. As for `dash` - that's the name of a POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Kubuntu v16.04 - not the version that you are - but I had to modify `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncomment `NAutoVTs=6` and restart.

Comment: I no longer experience this issue, since I switched distributions, but - damn, another systemd idiosyncracy :-(